# Make a 3D shape using Amulet

Tags: lua, game-development

I recently tried my hand at making a program using "**Amulet**" a Lua-based audio/visual toolkit (https://www.amulet.xyz/doc/) that lets you create interactive "visual experiences". I wanted to reproduce this -> [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExK0p.gif), i.e. a rotating geometric shape (a kind of Octahedron).

I have some basic programming skills, but I don't know anything about 3D. I'd be delighted if someone could give me some ideas on how to make a rotating geometric shape in three-dimensional space using Amulet.

Thank you !

I tried to make a 2d shape at first but I can't handle matrices and all the 3D related stuff.